# Apache proxy to back end services

Tags: apache-2.4

I need to create a conf file for apache web server (Linux) , that will act as proxy for multiple back end services om the same server. Each backend service is running as systemd service on separate ports.

The conf file contains following

```
<VirtualHost: *:80>
    ProxyPass /api/policies/???  http://127.0.0.1:6001/
    ProxyPassReverse /api/policies/???  http://127.0.0.1:6001/

    ProxyPass /api/policies/???/coverages http://127.0.0.1:6002/
    ProxyPassReverse /api/policies/???/coverages http://127.0.0.1:6002/

    ProxyPass /api/policies/???/premiums http://127.0.0.1:6003/
    ProxyPassReverse /api/policies/???/coverages http://127.0.0.1:6003/

</VirtualHost>
```

??? – refers to request parameter which will be part of the url
How do I define this in the conf ? what kind of expression needs to be used

Answer (score 2):

Several approaches are possible.

1. Enclose the ProxyPass directives in correctly ordered [`LocationMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#locationmatch) directives  ; something along the lines of

   ```
   <LocationMatch "/api/policies/(.*)/coverages">
       ProxyPass  http://127.0.0.1:6002/
       # ...
   </LocationMatch>
   <LocationMatch "/api/policies/(.*)/premiums">
       ProxyPass  http://127.0.0.1:6003/
       # ...
   </LocationMatch>
   <Location "/api/policies/">
       ProxyPass  http://127.0.0.1:6001/
       # ...
   </Location>
   ```
2. Use the mod_rewrite [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html) target `[P]`rather than ProxyPass directives to allow pattern matching.

   ```
    RewriteRule    "^/api/policies/(.*)/coverages/(.*)"  "http://127.0.0.1:6002/"  [P]
    RewriteRule    "^/api/policies/(.*)/premiums/(.*)"  "http://127.0.0.1:6003/"  [P]
   ```